# Freely rotate instances in Abaqus

Tags: python, rotation, translate, abaqus

I would like to manually rotate and translate instances of my Abaqus model without inserting values (see image). I don't have coordinates to translate the instance to, but I merely want an estimation of the final shape of my model. Therefore I want to 'manually' shift and drag the instances with my computermouse. I cannot find the buttons for it. Does anyone know if a certain option exists?
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: such an option does not exists in the Abaqus CAE